# Git: quais os possíveis fluxos para dois ambientes de desenvolvimento?

Tags: git, versionamento, git-flow

Estou configurando um ambiente de desenvolvimento com o Git em alguns dos meus projetos, a minha ideia inicial para projetos simples é:

- A branch master fica bloqueada, quando alguém precisa realizar alguma
  alteração é criada uma nova branch (igual a master), a alteração é
  feita e a pessoa abre um pull request para subir pra master. Até aqui
  ok.

O caso que estou com dúvidas é quando existe dois ambientes de desenvolvimento, por exemplo: master (produção) e develop (testes).

A minha ideia era o develop ser uma cópia da master, quando alguém precisar realizar alguma alteração, é criada uma branch da **develop** e ao terminar ela da um merge da branch na **develop**.

Na hora de fazer o merge da develop para a master, se eu tiver dado merge de várias branches para a develop, eu consigo especificar qual branch eu vou subir para a master?

Existem alguns fluxos mais usados? Ou boas práticas?

Não sei se ficou claro mas posso melhorar a explicação!

Atualizando:

Cheguei a um fluxo que acredito que seja viável:

Três ambientes criados para dois ambientes de desenvolvimento

- Master
- Dev
- Testes

A princípio todos são iguais, se alguém precisar realizar alguma feature/hotfix, ela cria sempre uma branch a partir da **Dev**, realiza a alteração e faz um merge com a branch **Testes**, se os testes estiverem ok, a pessoa realiza o merge da sua branch com a **Dev**, a branch **Testes** ficaria sempre para testar algo e a **Dev** seria tudo que está pronto para ir para a produção **(master**).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizando o Git Flow como organizador de branchs, utilizo da seguinte forma:

- **Branch master** - É a branch que contém código em nível de produção, ou seja, o código mais maduro existente na sua aplicação. Todo o código novo produzido eventualmente é juntado com a branch master, em algum momento do desenvolvimento;
- **Branch develop** - É a branch que contém código em nível preparatório para o próximo deploy. Ou seja, quando features são terminadas, elas são juntadas com a branch develop, testadas (em conjunto, no caso de mais de uma feature), e somente depois as atualizações da branch develop passam por mais um processo para então ser juntadas com a branch master;
- **Branches feature/*** - São branches no qual são desenvolvidos recursos novos para o projeto em questão. Essas branches tem por convenção nome começando com feature/ (exemplo: feature/new-layout) e são criadas a partir da branch develop (pois um recurso pode depender diretamente de outro recurso em algumas situações), e, ao final, são juntadas com a branch develop;
- **Branches hotfix/*** - São branches no qual são realizadas correções de bugs críticos encontrados em ambiente de produção, e que por isso são criadas a partir da branch master, e são juntadas diretamente com a branch master e com a branch develop;
- **Branches release/** * - São branches com um nível de confiança maior do que a branch develop, e que se encontram em nível de preparação para ser juntada com a branch master e com a branch develop (para caso tenha ocorrido alguma correção de bug na branch release/* em questão). Note que, nessas branches, bugs encontrados durante os testes das features que vão para produção podem ser corrigidos mais tranquilamente, antes de irem efetivamente para produção. Por convenção, essas branches tem o nome começando com release/ e terminando com o número da próxima versão do software (seguindo o exemplo do hotfix, dado acima, seria algo como release/2.32.0), normalmente seguindo as regras do versionamento semântico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: olá, você consegue me dar um exemplo mais prático? Apesar de conhecer o git flow na prática com muitas pessoas está complicado pra mim

Comment: Você tem que levar em conta que o Git Flow estabelece algumas regras de nomenclaturas para tipos de branches enquanto, ao mesmo tempo, define o que cada tipo de branch faz. Tome de exemplo a imagem a cima. Na prática, utilizo basicamente dessa forma.