# Git Flow : criar nova hotfix com uma branch feature em andamento, sem perder modificações da branch feature

Tags: git-flow

Quais passos são necessários para "interromper temporariamente" uma branch feature "xxx" em andamento ?

O objetivo é criar uma nova branch HotFix para uma correção de emergência, e retornar para a mesma branch feature/"xxx" no ponto em que foi interrompida, para continuar o trabalho.

1-) preciso "salvar" antes todo o trabalho nesta feature ? tem que dar git add . ? git commit nela ?

2-) Ao criar nova branch HotFix, git flow hotfix start 'minha.hotfix' :

- Preciso dar um git checkout pra branch master antes ? Ou, posso criar a HotFix dentro a feature mesmo ?

3-) Após terminar o trabalho na branch HotFix, git flow hotfix finish 'minha.hotfix' :

- o git flow já me posiciona na branch develop. Basta dar um git checkout para minha branch feature/"xxx" tudo estará lá exatamente no ponto onde parei antes de criar a branch hotfix ? ou, precisa de mais providências ?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A forma mais segura de gerenciar essa situação é a seguinte:

- Primeiramente, salve, guarde ou descarte todo o trabalho da sua feature, o que for mais adequado pra você no momento.
- Seguindo as definições do GitFlow, você criará uma branch de hotfix a partir da sua branch master.
- Em seguida, após a correção for aprovada, ela será enviada de volta para a master e para a sua develop através de uma release.
- Depois, retorne normalmente a sua feature e continue seu trabalho.
- Caso queira atualizar sua feature já com o hotfix feito, você tem a opção de já baixar as atualizações da sua develop dentro da sua feature.

Aqui tem uma imagem interessante de outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332969/git-quais-os-poss%C3%ADveis-fluxos-para-dois-ambientes-de-desenvolvimento?rq=1) ilustrando como esse fluxo funciona

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]